# why I cant import fire base libraries in android studio after adding needed dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I need add fire store for my project. I followed all the steps to add the fire store. Gradle build and compilation was successful after the build. But when I tried to code its didnt not allowing to import firestore libraries . Following code is my build gradle

```
  plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    
    }
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.mas"
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    
        packagingOptions{
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    
        implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-installations:17.0.0')
        implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.0'
    
    
    }
```

This code is the gradle for project level.

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'




        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMHto.png)

Answer (score 0):

why are you saying that this import is wrong? you screenshot shows no errors when importing lib classes, greyed out lines means that these imports are in fact working, but aren't needed in this particular class, as they aren't used in code. put some firebase-related code in some methods or declare variables and greyed-out lines become "colored"

when you can't import declared classes then these import lines are underlined with red color

Answer (score 0):

just formate your code and check that grey import get remove if it is in red color then it will be error
you are not using them